# Unit Test WebExtensions

Tags: unit-testing, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

How do you unit test web extensions?

For older Firefox extensions, the deprecated `jpm` tool had a `jpm test` command, which ran unit tests on methods exported from the `.js` files. Is this anyhow possible with [`web-ext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext)? Or by hand? How about Google Chrome Extensions?

As an example, take the following `background.js`:

```
function redirect(requestDetails) {
    console.log("Redirecting: " + requestDetails.url);
    return { redirectUrl: requestDetails.uri + '&helloworld'};
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    redirect,
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}
);
```

How to test `redirect()`?

**Update**: https://github.com/google/gjstest might be used for this. I have not gotten around to using it, though.

**Update**: after the answer, it seems as though [Mocha](http://mochajs.org/) might work more easily than Jasmine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While gjstest looks promising, you need to recompile the v8-engine on everything except OS X, which might be too cumbersome for a general solution.

[Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/pages/getting_started.html) is easy to set up.

1. download from https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/releases, f.ex. https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/releases/download/v2.5.2/jasmine-standalone-2.5.2.zip
2. unzip this zip file to separate directory, f.ex. `addon-dir/test`
3. alter `SpecRunner.html`, replace

   ```
   <script src="src/Player.js"></script>
   <script src="src/Song.js"></script>
   ```

   with

   ```
   <script src="path/to/background.js"></script
   ```

   and replace

   ```
   <script src="spec/SpecHelper.js"></script>
   <script src="spec/PlayerSpec.js"></script>
   ```

   with

   ```
   <script src="spec/AddonSpec.js"></script>
   ```
4. create the file `spec/AddonSpec.js`, with content

   ```
   describe("Addon", function() {
       it("should append hello world", function() {
           let details = {uri: "google.de/q=test"};

           expect(redirect(details)).toEqual(details.uri + "&helloworld");
       });
   });
   ```
5. open the file `SpecRunner.html` in the browser of your choice.